# Why is there no NSShort or NSByte?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Newbie in IOS programming here.

I was looking at the Foundation Types Data Reference and have started to use the **NSInteger** typedef on the assumption that it will make my app more portable.  However I often have a use for 16-bit and 8-bit integers and I don't see an **NSShort** or **NSByte**.

It seems wasteful to allocate a 32/64 bit variable for something that has a small range, say 0 to 12.

Are there any symbols that are defined for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` if you want types that are a specific size. There are also similar types for 32 and 64 bits values.

Comment: What package are those symbols defined in?   will they be generally portable between Cocoa and Cocoa Touch?

Comment: `uint8_t` is defined in `/usr/include/types/_unit8_t.h` as an `unsigned char`. `uint16_t` is `unsigned short`. I haven't verified but given the goal of the types to be a fixed size, it would make sense they are the same size in both Cocoa Touch and Cocoa.

Comment: They are standard "C" found in <stdint.h>. The sizes are as expected and the same across platforms.